# Code compiles in ideone but not with gcc

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int v()
    return 0;
}
```

I ran it in [ideone](http://ideone.com/LOedLL), and it compiled successfully. I have the same code in file `test1.cpp` on my computer, I ran `g++ test1.cpp` and I got the following error:

```
./test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./test1.cpp:7:2: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘return’
```

Why dose this happen? is this a bug?
I'm using linux mint, gcc version 4.7.

Comment: now add the same semicolon in your actual code and recompile

Comment: how are you compiling this? What is your actual compile command?

Comment: *face slap. ok try with g++-4.8 test1.cpp

Comment: @BryanChen I don't think it is a type see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/255fdbabb31bcb11) generates the same error message without the semicolon and ideoone will generate the same error as well if you fork and remove it.

Comment: @BryanChen I am rolling back b/c there is no way to generate the error message w/o the missing `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon here:

```
 int v()
        ^
```

should be:

```
 int v() ;
```

which is a function declaration, not clear that was what was intended though. If you want to initialize `v` then the following would work:

```
 int v(0) ;
```

or in *C++11*:

```
 int v{0} ;
```

Comment: Just a typo here on SO; his linked code includes the semicolon.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/255fdbabb31bcb11) generates the same error message as described but if you add the `;` the error message goes away. So it does not look like a typo at all.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill his linked code is irrelevant, and it compiler. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly known as C++'s most vexing parse. When you do something like

```
int f();
```

the compiler reads this as a function prototype, declaring a function `f` that returns an `int`. If you're using C++11, you should instead do

```
int f{}; // f initialized to 0
```

if you're not using C++11, make sure to initialize the variable right away.

Comment: This should not cause a compilation failure. It is perfectly fine to declare a function in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolon after

```
int v();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideone is using gcc 4.8.1 for your code (as you can see in your own link) while you are using 4.7

There are [several difference](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) regarding C++ 11 implementation, and apparently it is affected by the line that looks like a function delcaration.